# python search rows in excel using 2 inputed information

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

i need a python program that reads excel files like these and ask for 2 specific information if the inputed information is in the same row the program will show us all the other information from that row

here is the excel file (and a example of what i need sorry it's bad):

[image: the excel file the information types the program will ask from and a example of a row]

the program i got but i can't get the search to work

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import xlrd
import xlwt


fen = Tk()
fen.geometry('320x600')

lf1=LabelFrame(fen,text='Informations')
lf1.place(x=10,y=10,width=300,height=300)

Label(lf1,text='fichier excel :').place(x=10,y=20)
Label(lf1,text='Référence :').place(x=10,y=60)
Label(lf1,text='Famille :').place(x=20,y=140)
Label(lf1,text='Type :').place(x=20,y=220)

def add() :
    file=askopenfilename(filetypes=[("EXCEL","*.xlsx")])

    if file == '': # I don't know why do you do this exactly, but just made it look cleaner for you
      return

    print(file)
    
        
fichier=ttk.Button(lf1,text='Ajouter',command=add)
fichier.place(x=120,y=20)

ref=Entry(lf1)
ref.place(x=100,y=55)

famille=Entry(lf1,state='disabled')
famille.place(x=100,y=135)

typ=Entry(lf1,state='disabled')
typ.place(x=100,y=220)

def r1():
    famille.configure(state='normal')
    typ.configure(state='disabled')

    
def r2():
    famille.configure(state='disabled')
    typ.configure(state='normal')

vals = ['A', 'B']
etiqs = ['Managers','techniciens']
varGr = StringVar()

r1=ttk.Radiobutton(lf1, variable=varGr, text=etiqs[0], value=vals[0],command=r1)
r2=ttk.Radiobutton(lf1, variable=varGr, text=etiqs[1], value=vals[1],command=r2)

r1.place(x=10,y=100)
r2.place(x=10,y=180)

#df=pd.read('file')
```

Comment: did u try `openpyxl` module?

Comment: yes but i don't really understand it well you see i am still new to python and coding but i must do this something big is depending on it i am really desperate

Comment: well, u have to take a deep breath and just believe u can do it, and then watch videos on youtube about it and integrate it with tkinter, and its not hard as u think at all. if u have more doubts, u can ask here

Comment: well i have been trying for 4 days now but i guess i can do research on `openpyxl`

Comment: do you have discord? add me my discord is "the one sad retrad Sed 100%#1327" so i can ask a couple of questions if possible

Comment: but idk openpyxl, i havent had the use of working with it